# Incease height of bottom modal Sheet when keyboard opens

Tags: flutter

[enter image description here][1]

When the user taps the field it should go up above the keyboard.
is it possible?

Comment: Image did not load.

Answer (score 0):

im not sure to increase the height. but you can scroll up the list by add `padding`

```
Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
  child: ListView(
     // list of your Textfield
  )
)
```

Result:

[image: result]

you can read my article here: https://medium.com/easyread/my-september-flutter-notes-700907827c7f